# Opacity control for KmlLayer in Google Maps V3 API?

Tags: google-maps, kml

Using a KmlLayer object within the Google Maps API, is it possible to control the opacity of a KML's image overlay features ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651930/using-a-kmllayer-object-within-the-google-maps-api-is-it-possible-to-allow-a-use)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it takes KML, sets a 50% opacity (static)
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_KML_samples_zoom_false.html
 slider could control the opacity setting

Slider control (not KML) but impressive

http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles_N1.html

Answer (score 0):

This transparency / opacity control for Google Maps API v3 might be adaptable to your needs:

http://www.gavinharriss.com/code/opacity-control

Disclosure: I developed the control.